# Объекты и стили javascript

Tags: javascript, pure_js

**Добрый вечер!**

Изучаю JS... и в связи с этим есть несколько вопросов:

1. Есть функция, которая берет из объекта некоторые значения и использует их в качестве CSS свойств. 
   *Почему при установке цвета границы(border) блока, не получается использовать x-1*, при

   var x = box.bg.length; ?

*Приходится использовать следующий код* -

```
block.style.border = box.border + 'px' + ' solid ' + box.bg[5];
```

*а это, как мне кажется, не очень оптимизированный подход.*

1. Есть ли более оптимизированный вариант задания стилей для элементов, а то, на мой взгляд, пять строчек кода для пяти свойств - это грубо...

**И еще**, хотелось бы услышать **Ваше мнение** и **критику** если необходимо, по коду в целом.

Вот то, что я понаписал:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var box = {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        bg: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'aqua', 'black'],
        border: 2
    };

    function blockShow(css) {
        for(i = 0; i < box.bg.length - 1; i++) {
            var x = box.bg[i],
                a = box.bg.length,
                block = document.createElement('div');

            block.style.backgroundColor = x;
            block.style.width = box.width + 'px';
            block.style.height = box.height + 'px';
            block.style.height = box.height + 'px';
            block.style.border = box.border + 'px' + ' solid ' + box.bg[5]; // 1 вопрос
            block.style.marginBottom = box.border + 'px';

            document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(block);
        }
    }
    blockShow(box);

}
```

HTML, соответственно:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**А вот живьем** - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/5jYmC/

Comment: я конечно понимаю что ты учишь js и всё такое, но было бы проще закинуть все стили в css с привязкой по классам, а затем в цикле создавать элементы с заведёнными классами

Comment: @Astor оба комментария перевел в один ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var box = {
   'width': '100px',
   'height': '100px',
   'border': '2px solid',
   'background': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'aqua', 'black'],
   'margin-bottom': '2px'
};

function blockShow(css, bg) {

   var block = document.createElement('div'),
       toStyles = 'background: '+css.background[bg]+';';

   for(var i in css) {
      if(i == 'background')
         continue;

      toStyles += i+':'+css[i]+';';
   }

   block.style.cssText  = toStyles;

   document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(block);

}

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
   blockShow(box, i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jYmC/1/ ну как-то так. По моему значение удобней хранить в объекте, т.к. их в будущем можно будет легко поменять, не затрагивая функцию. Да и функция становиться менее заточена под определенную работу и становится более свободной.

[[@Astor](/users/8823/astor)](/users/8823/astor) Плюсы используются для соединения строк. Про цикл: цикл перебирает все элементы массива box. По-этому нужно исключить background из перебора, т.е. если ключ равен background, то пропускаем эту итерацию цикла. И последнее: цикл я добавил просто так, просто я отделил функцию создания блока и она стала универсальней, чем ежели одна функция была бы предназначена только для создания этих пяти блоков.

Вот еще одно улучшение придумал.

Можно вместо

```
  if(i == 'background')
     continue;
```

добавить вот это в начало функции:

```
   var block = document.createElement('div'),
       toStyles = 'background: '+css.background[bg]+';';

   delete css.background;
```

Тогда получится чуть короче и менее затратнее:

```
var box = {
   'width': '100px',
   'height': '100px',
   'border': '2px solid',
   'background': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'aqua', 'black'],
   'margin-bottom': '2px'
};

function blockShow(css, bg, wrap) {

   var block = document.createElement('div'),
       toStyles = 'background: '+css.background[bg]+';';

   delete css.background;

   for(var i in css) {
      toStyles += i+':'+css[i]+';';
   }

   block.style.cssText  = toStyles;

   wrap.appendChild(block);      
}

var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
   blockShow(box, i, wrapper);
}
```

Comment: обращаться в цикле к `document.getElementById('wrapper')` в цикле не самая лучшая практика, тем более, вы говорите 

>Да и функция становиться менее заточена под определенную работу и становится более свободной

может wrapper тоже передавать как аргумент

Comment: @Spectre так и document можно закешировать. Надо подправить.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function blockShow(box) {
    for(var/*не забываем*/ i = 0, l = box.bg.length - 1/*кэшируем*/; i < l; i++) {
        var x = box.bg[i],
            a = box.bg.length,
            block = document.createElement('div'),
            style = block.style, // кэшируем
            wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'); // кэшируем

        style.backgroundColor = x;
        style.width = box.width + 'px';
        // ...

        wrapper.appendChild(block);
    }
}
```

первый вопрос не до конца понятен, какого результата хотите добиться?

Comment: @Spectre, спасибо. Имелось ввиду уменьшение объема CSS в JS.

Хотя конечно лучшим вариантом, я думаю, будет задание стилей в CSS а не в js, делал так для тренировки и пополнения багажа знаний...

Comment: естественно, создать блок с определённым классом куда правильнее

Answer (score 1):

Я как то привык работать с объектами в js если box у вас примитив блока я бы описал так

```
var box = function(){
    this.height = 100;
    this.width = 100;
    ....
    this.show = function(){
    .... 
    } 
}

//когда нужно создать блок такой
var bx1 = new box();
bx1.show();
```

ну и для  прописания стилей отедльно свойство класса, а так в js 
объектDOM.setAttribute('style','все стили как в html когда на элементе прописываешь'); задать можно все стили 1 строчкой. Например

```
var md = document.body;
md.setAttribute('style','background-color: #ff00ff; color: #000000;');
```

Преобразовал в ответ по просьбе задавшего вопрос
[демка](http://jsfiddle.net/6hDbV/)

Comment: @ilyas, комментарий "о преобразовании в ответ" был обращен к @lampa. К Вам был обращен следующий...

На сколько я могу понять, Вы используете конструктор...
Я в своем изучении до них пока не дошел, это будет следующим шагом.
В Вашей демке выводится один блок, а необходимо вывести его в цикле, как показано в примере.

Comment: Я показл как вывести 1 по циклу все просто внутри цикла создаешь объект выводишь и все

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wr3F7/

выводит 101 блоков с разными бекграундами (:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ETPkX/
для полного счастья (:

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {

    var box = {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        bg: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'aqua', 'black'],
        border: 2
    };

    function blockShow(css) { // объявление функции здесь излишнее
    // так же как и переменной css, которая не используется совсем
    // объект box в данном случае будет виден изнутри функции 
    // нет необходимости передавать его как аргумент
        for(i = 0; i < box.bg.length - 1; i++) { 
        // здесь цикл считает длину массива на каждой итерации            
        // кроме того там происходит операция вычитания
        // это влияет на скорость, кэшируйте в переменную            
            var x = box.bg[i], // всегда давайте переменным осмысленные имена
                a = box.bg.length, // хотя бы старайтесь
                block = document.createElement('div');

            block.style.backgroundColor = x;
            block.style.width = box.width + 'px'; 
            block.style.height = box.height + 'px'; 
            block.style.height = px(box.height); 
            block.style.border = box.border + 'px' + ' solid ' + box.bg[5]; // 1 вопрос
            block.style.marginBottom = box.border + 'px';

            document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(block);
        }
    }
    blockShow(box);

}
```